# How can I supply the 3 splash screen sizes for a Windows 8 app?

Tags: windows-8, splash-screen, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I'm trying to create a Windows 8 C#/XAML app, and the first task I'd like to do is to set up the splash screen.

How can I supply the 100%, 140% and 180% versions as referenced in the [Splash screen element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211467.aspx) docs?

That link refers to [Tiles overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh779724.aspx), which then links to [Tile image sizes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh781198.aspx), which then links to [Globalizing tile and toast notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh831183.aspx), which gives both a folder naming convention and file naming convention, neither of which seem to work for the Splash screen.

Why it could not be a nice appxmanifest entry?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you have your basic project template where there is a file called SplashScreen.png in the Assets folder - you don't need to change Package.appxmanifest. Just rename SplashScreen.png to SplashScreen.scale-100.png and add SplashScreen.scale-140.png as well as SplashScreen.scale-180.png (at 868x420 and 1116x540 resolutions respectively) to the Assets project folder and the system will pick them up depending on current scale when the app starts. It is easy to test in the simulator (Project/Properties/Debug/Simulator, then hit Change Resolution in the simulator and rerun the app to see different splash screen images). I think the Package.appxmanifest editor does not allow to pick a splash screen file that does not exist, so if you don't have SplashScreen.png, but SplashScreen.scale-100.png - you won't be able to select it, but you can edit the manifest file in a text editor.

I think it is what they meant when they said in the [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211467.aspx) when they said "The splash screen image can be given as either a direct path to an **image file** or as a **resource**".

Comment: I am so annoyed you are right, by ignoring the instructions about 'other' scaled app images and having an unused SplashScreen.png as well as the *-scale-%.png images in the Asset folder does the job.
Tried all the resolutions in the simulator and
10.6" 1024 x 768  100%
10.6" 1920 x 1080 140%
10.6" 2560 x 1440 180%
12"   1280 x 800  100%
23" 1920x1080 100%

Comment: I don't understand this. You need to provide 4(?) images then where one image is there twice - seems a bit odd, doesn't it? Can you explain the correct and optimal way a bit more?

Comment: The ".scale-100" and the likes are resource qualifiers and when you have assets with these qualifiers - you reference them without the qualifiers and the platform picks the right one for the job. Depending on screen size/resolution - the right resolution version of your splash screen image will be picked up.

Comment: yes, I understand that but as per the question how do you properly specify a splash screen image then. You cannot link to the .scale-100 image so you would need the original.png, the .scale-100.png, the .scale-140.png and the .scale-180.png - this works (I've tested) but seems a bit odd that you have to have both the original.png **and** the .scale-100.png since they are identical apart from the name!

Comment: You don't need the one without the qualifier after you specify it as the one to use.